# In Angular 4 BarchartData Doesnt Taking IndexLabel

Tags: angular, chart.js

In Angular 4 I Am Not Getting Index For Each Bar I Am Using This Code, Whether It Works

```
enter code here
this.barChartData=[{
data:[10,20,30,40,50],label:"Serial",indexLabel:["A","B","C","D","E"]
}];
```

Comment: Would you please clarify what your problem is and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: In Barchart Top Of Each Bar I Need IndexLabel As "A","B","C","D","E"..

Comment: Will you show your html and any other relevant code to the bar chart? The code you provided is to limited to provide you with any information.